# What analysis can I perform for constrained optimalization of coil parameters

Tags: optimization, constraint

I have about 20 discrete sets of variable coil parameters that I need to assign values to, satisfying given constraints. The objective is to minimize the manufacturing cost (and to satisfy the constrains).

The parameters are of two different kinds: some are integers (e.g. length and width), and some are strings (e.g. type of material). Also, parameters like the material type are linked to predefined tables with manufacturing sizes, so there is no apparent dependence between the table value and the parameters. For example, we get the list of usable wire widths for the current coil height and its material from these tables.

From these parameters and the corresponding manufacturing table values, we then evaluate a large number of interlinked equations (with basic mathematical operations only), getting other coil properties like its cooling properties and effectiveness. All of these calculated properties are constrained (both their mean and maximum values need to be within a given range). With all parameters assigned, we can also calculate the cost of the coil (the objective function).

I was asked to help out with the optimization of this problem, but I am completely new to optimization, and I cannot seem to find the right way. I believe that we cannot use linear programming since we not only have non-numeric variables, but we also take some values from the manufacturing tables. I think we need to use some sort of a global optimization algorithm like simulated annealing, but I would like to avoid guessing its parameters... I would be glad if someone would point me in a better direction or to a more suitable algorithm for this.